# How to get event id for particular month fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How to get all events id for particular month?

```
var source = { events: [
                           {
                             title  : val.xxxxName,
                             start  : val.StartDate,
                             end    : val.EndDate,
                             xxxxDetailID : val.xxxxDetailID,
                          }
                ]};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );
```

I have lots of event for month. I can get all events by using:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

But I need only one months event ids.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd pass the month desired as a parameter? I meant do you want it this way: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', 'January'); ?

Comment: @MarloC Yeap... $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', 'January'); - for this I am getting only black array :( ...... I need only one months all events.... month should be variable

Answer (score 3):

When I look at the documentation [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) I see that you can set a custom filter.

Something like this should work...

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents',function(event){
    /*Gets the events of the current month in an array*/
    if (event.start.getMonth() == $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {   
        return false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should let you pass in any month you want.

Declare an Enum for months.

```
var Months = { January: 0, February: 1, March: 2, ... };
```

Pass in your desired month.

```
var desiredMonth = Months.January;

function getEventsForMonth(desiredMonth) {
    var result = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < source.events.length; i++) {
        if(source.events[i].getMonth() == desiredMonth ) {
            result.push(source.events[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', getEventsForMonth(desiredMonth));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/723/) , click on next and prev buttons .. it will show events in particular month.

```
.....
....
function getEventsForCurrentMonth(){
  for(var i=0; i< events.length; i++) {
    if (events[i].start.getMonth() == $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth()) {
       monthEvents.push(events[i].id);             
    } 
   }   
}
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your way of getting events in the `loading` function of fullCalendar.

Look at this example,

```
loading: function(){
              var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
}
```

Within `eventAfterAllRender` callback, get the `id` of events for the required month within a loop.